# Really Confusing Question on Wronskian and ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

The following question was given to as in a recent assignment, namely

Let $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0~.$$ It is given that $(1+t)^2$ is a solution to this differential equation, and that the wronskian of any two solutions is constant. Find the coefficients of $p$ and $q$.

Say for example the wronskian is a constant, say $C$. Then if $u$ is another solution, then $$u'+ \frac{2u}{(1+t)^2} = C~,$$ from which I get $$u = \frac{Ct+A}{(1+t)^2}~,$$ where $A$ is another constant.

How do I obtain the coefficients $p$ and $q$ ? I could solve simultaneous equations, but then they are messy, as the second derivative of $q$ would involve many terms.

How can Abel's identity for differential equations help me? Another problem is that I don't know if the wronskian is $0$ or not.

But $p$ and $q$ are analytic, so if their wronskian is zero then the two functions are linearly dependent; just putting some facts together.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: You should use `y''` (two apostrophes) rather than `y"`, to get $y''$ instead of $y"$.

Comment: I get that the Wronskian is $$ \left|\begin{array}{cc} (1+t)^2 & u(t) \\ 2(1+t) & u'(t)\end{array}\right|$$ which implies $$ u'(t) = \frac{2 u(t)}{1+t} + \frac{C}{(1+t)^2}.$$

Comment: Actually, it is best to write the Wronskian condition as $$ u'(t)(1+t)^2 = 2 u(t)(1+t) + C. $$  I would take derivatives and start plugging values.  Are $p$ and $q$ supposed to be polynomials or arbitrary functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DJC pointed out, the differential equation you get by setting the Wronskian to a constant is
$$u'(t) = {2 \over 1 + t} u(t) + {C \over (1 + t)^2}$$
This is a first-order linear equation which is solved by the usual methods to
$$u(t) = -{C' \over 1 + t} + D(1 + t)^2$$
We can choose any of these to be the second solution, other than a multiple of the first solution $(1 + t)^2$. So we take $u(t) = {1 \over 1 + t}$. To find out what $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are, you can just plug your two solutions into the original equation and solve for $p(t)$ and $q(t)$. The first one gives
$$2(1 + t)p(t) + (1 + t)^2 q(t) = -2$$
The second one gives 
$$-{1 \over (1 + t)^2}p(t) + {1 \over 1 + t}q(t) = -2{1 \over (1 + t)^3}$$
or equivalently
$$-(1 + t)p(t) + (1 + t)^2q(t) = -2$$
Subtract these equations to get $p(t) = 0$. Then solve for $q(t) = -2{1 \over (1 + t)^2}$.

---

Edit: The Wronskian is actually of the form $Ce^{-\int p(t)}$ by something known as Abel's identity. So if you are willing to use that, you can shorten your work by getting $p(t) = 0$ immediately this way. Then you can just plug in your first solution and solve for $q(t)$.